# Zipping two dataframes in c# Deedle

Tags: dataframe, deedle

would anyone be able to provide me with a working example of dataframe zipping in C#? I am bit lost in the operation.
Thanks!

Comment: Please go through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The `frame.Zip` operation is the same thing as `zipAlign` in the more documented F# API, so have a look at `zipAlign` in [this section of the documentation](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-framemodule.html#section4).

Given a frame `df1`:

```
     A 
1 -> 1 
2 -> 2
```

And a frame `df2`:

```
     A 
2 -> 2 
3 -> 3
```

When you call `df1.Zip(df2, (int a, int b) -> a + b)`, you get:

```
     A         
1 -> <missing> 
2 -> 4         
3 -> <missing>
```

That is, for cells where both frames contain a value, `a + b` is calculated. For all other cells, you get a missing value. Note that you need type annotations in the lambda function - this has to match the type of values in the frame (for not matching types, the function just returns the values from the first frame unchanged).

Comment: Is there a way to handle 1 -> <missing>  this condition?